# Not understanding why context creation failing with win32 api and OpenGL and wgl

Tags: c, opengl, wgl

So i have followed all of the fundamental instructions in windows creation for OpenGL rendering context

the problem is to do when i try to create a core profile context with opengl , it fails and i get the "the program stopped working" message from windows when i run the a.exe file, there is no indication where the problem exists and what is causing the problem , i even tried to run gdb but it only refers to the function

wglCreateContextAttribsARB and no other information is given

here is my files which are currently included in the program

mainWin.c

```
#include "mainWin.h"
#include "glPart.c"



//main function, point of entry for windows application 
//must be present in a windows application

INT WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
               LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
   MSG        Msg;  //variable for storing messages retrieved from operating system by using GetMessage
   HWND       hWnd;
   WNDCLASS   WndCls;

   // Create the window object
   //sends a WM_CREATE message to windows which doesnt get processed until you retrieve messages and process them 

   //initialize window class must be initialized no default class 
   initWinClass(&WndCls, hInstance);
   //Register the application must register application to make it available to other controls 
   RegisterClass(&WndCls);

   hWnd = CreateWindow(ClsName,
                       WndName,
                       WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                       CW_USEDEFAULT,
                       CW_USEDEFAULT,
                       640,
                       640,
                       NULL,
                       NULL,
                       hInstance,
                       NULL);

   //printf("at initialization %x\n",hWnd);

   // Find out if the window was created
   if( !hWnd ) // If the window was not created,
      return 0; // stop the application

   printf("Window was created....\n");   

   // Display the window to the user
   ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
   UpdateWindow(hWnd);

   initGL(hDC);

   //GLint a, b;

   while (Msg.message != WM_QUIT)
   {
      while (PeekMessage (&Msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE) > 0) //Or use an if statement
      {
          TranslateMessage (&Msg);
          DispatchMessage (&Msg);
      }
     //Here is were all the "animation that isn't used when the user does something" code will go.
      renderTri();
      SwapBuffers(hDC);
   }

   return Msg.wParam;
}
```

winMain.h

```
#define true 1
#define false 0

#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/wglew.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>

LPCTSTR ClsName = "OpenGL App";
LPCTSTR WndName = "My Game";
//global hdc
HDC hDC;

PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd = {
      sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR),          //size of structure
      1,                                      //default version
      PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW |                    //window drawing support
      PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL |                    //opengl support
      PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER,                       //double buffering support
      PFD_TYPE_RGBA,                          //RGBA color mode
      32,                                     //32 bit color mode
      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,                       //ignore color bits
      0,                                      //no alpha buffer
      0,                                      //ignore shift bit
      0,                                      //no accumulation buffer
      0, 0, 0, 0,                             //ignore accumulation bits
      24,                                     //16 bit z-buffer size
      8,                                      //stencil buffer
      0,                                      //no aux buffer
      PFD_MAIN_PLANE,                         //main drawing plane
      0,                                      //reserved
      0, 0, 0 };                              //layer masks ignored

//context attributes
int attribs[] =
{
   WGL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB, 3,
   WGL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB, 1,
   WGL_CONTEXT_FLAGS_ARB, 0,
   WGL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK_ARB, WGL_CONTEXT_CORE_PROFILE_BIT_ARB, 
   0
};


LRESULT CALLBACK WndProcedure(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

void initWinClass(PWNDCLASS WndCls, HINSTANCE hInstance){

   // Create the application window
   //WndCls.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX); wndclassex
   WndCls->style         = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW |CS_OWNDC;  
   //the style member variable specifies the primary operations applied on the window class
   //if user moves or changes its size, you would need the window redrawn to get its characteristics 
   //CS_HREDRAW CS_VREDRAW draw the window vertically and horizontally  
   WndCls->lpfnWndProc   = WndProcedure;
   WndCls->cbClsExtra    = 0;
   WndCls->cbWndExtra    = 0;
   WndCls->hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
   WndCls->hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
   WndCls->hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH); //cast to HBRUSH 
   WndCls->lpszMenuName  = NULL;
   WndCls->lpszClassName = ClsName;
   WndCls->hInstance     = hInstance;
   //WndCls.hIconSm       = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION); wndclassex

}

void setupPixelFormat(HDC hDC){

   int nPixelFormat;

   /*      Choose best matching format*/
   nPixelFormat = ChoosePixelFormat(hDC, &pfd);

   if (nPixelFormat == 0) printf("Error in choose pixel format\n");

   /*      Set the pixel format to the device context*/
   BOOL bResult = SetPixelFormat(hDC, nPixelFormat, &pfd);

   if (!bResult) printf("Error in set pixel format\n");


}

void setupPixelFormatARB(HDC hDC){

   const int attribList[] =
   {
     WGL_DRAW_TO_WINDOW_ARB, GL_TRUE,
     WGL_SUPPORT_OPENGL_ARB, GL_TRUE,
     WGL_DOUBLE_BUFFER_ARB, GL_TRUE,
     WGL_PIXEL_TYPE_ARB, WGL_TYPE_RGBA_ARB,
     WGL_COLOR_BITS_ARB, 32,
     WGL_DEPTH_BITS_ARB, 24,
     WGL_STENCIL_BITS_ARB, 8,
     0,        //End
   };

   int pixelFormat;
   UINT numFormats;

   wglChoosePixelFormatARB(hDC, attribList, NULL, 1, &pixelFormat, &numFormats);
   SetPixelFormat(hDC, pixelFormat, &pfd);


}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProcedure(HWND hWnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
   //printf("the message %d memory address is %x\n", Msg, hWnd);   

   static HGLRC hRC;

    switch(Msg)
    {
    //this is the favourite message you can use to perform any early processing that you want to make 
    //sure happens before most things show up you can use this message to initialize anything in your application
    //The window procedure of the new window receives this message after the window is created, 
    //but before the window becomes visible.
    //will only run once on creation
    case WM_CREATE:
       hDC = GetDC(hWnd);   //get the device context for window
       setupPixelFormat(hDC); //call our pixel format setup function

       //in order to use ARB context creation you must create a render context
       //must be made active and destroyed 
       HGLRC tempContext = wglCreateContext(hDC);
       wglMakeCurrent(hDC, tempContext);

       hRC = wglCreateContextAttribsARB(hDC,0, attribs);
       wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL);
       wglDeleteContext(tempContext);
       wglMakeCurrent(hDC, hRC);

      wglMakeCurrent(hDC,hRC);  //make rendering context current old style
    break;

    //minimum application needs to deal with: 
    //wm_destroy message to close window and default case for non registered default messaging processing
    //otherwise hanging or not reaching event queue  

    case WM_DESTROY: //Sent when a window is being destroyed. 
                     //It is sent to the window procedure of the window being destroyed after the window is removed from the screen.
    //you can use this message to deconstruct the window once the user requests to destroy the window
       wglMakeCurrent(hDC,NULL);    //deselect rendering context
       wglDeleteContext(hRC);       //delete rendering context
       PostQuitMessage(0);      //The PostQuitMessage function posts a WM_QUIT message to the thread's message queue and returns immediately
       //send wm_quit message 
       //Indicates a request to terminate an application, and is generated when the application calls the PostQuitMessage function. 
       //This message causes the GetMessage function to return zero.
       printf("Window destroyed goodbye...bye");
    break;

    //this must exist to process left over messages or the application will hang or will not go forward through the 
    //event queue and the while loop will 
    default:
        // Process the left-over messages and messages that are not dealt with
       return DefWindowProc(hWnd, Msg, wParam, lParam);
    break;
    }
    // If something was not done, let it go
    return 0;
}
```

and finally glPart.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>

void initGL(HDC hDC){

   //set experimental value to true so that all functions can be used
       glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;

       //initialize glew and get result , check result is not a failure 
       GLenum err = glewInit();
       if(err!=GLEW_OK){
          printf("glew failed!!!....");     
       }

   //wglGetProcAddress("wglGetExtensionsStringARB")

   printf("OpenGL version string is %s\n", glGetString(GL_VERSION));

   GLint OpenGLVersion[3];

   glGetIntegerv(GL_MAJOR_VERSION, &OpenGLVersion[0]);
   glGetIntegerv(GL_MINOR_VERSION, &OpenGLVersion[1]);

   printf("Glew version is %s\n", glewGetString(GLEW_VERSION));
   printf("GL Major version %d\nGL Minor Version %d\n", OpenGLVersion[0], OpenGLVersion[1]);
   printf("GLSL version is %s \nVendor of OpenGL is %s \nRenderer version is %s\n", glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION), 
                                                                                    glGetString(GL_VENDOR) ,glGetString(GL_RENDERER));
   // Enable settings 
   glEnable(GL_BLEND);
   glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

}
void renderTri(){

   //finally some drawing OpenGL

   GLuint vao;
   glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
   glBindVertexArray(vao);

   // An array of 3 vectors which represents 3 vertices
   static const GLfloat verticies[] = {
     -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
      1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
      0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
   };

   // This will identify our vertex buffer
   GLuint vbo;
   // Generate 1 buffer, put the resulting identifier in vertexbuffer
   glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
   // The following commands will talk about our 'vertexbuffer' buffer
   glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
   // Give our vertices to OpenGL.
   glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(verticies), verticies, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

   // 1rst attribute buffer : vertices
   glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
   glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
   glVertexAttribPointer(
      0,                  // attribute 0. No particular reason for 0, but must match the layout in the shader.
      3,                  // size
      GL_FLOAT,           // type
      GL_FALSE,           // normalized?
      0,                  // stride
      (void*)0            // array buffer offset
   );
   // Draw the triangle !
   glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3); // Starting from vertex 0; 3 vertices total -> 1 triangle
   glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

}
```

now if i do this the old way without wglCreateContextAttribsARB it works fine and does what it is supposed to do even without the shaders , but when i try to do this by creating a core profile context with wgl is when the program fails

i compile with

```
gcc -Wall -Werror mainWin.c -lopengl32 -lglew32 -lgdi32
```

and no error are given

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's have a look at your code here:

> ```
> case WM_CREATE:
>    hDC = GetDC(hWnd);   //get the device context for window
>    setupPixelFormat(hDC); //call our pixel format setup function
>
>    //in order to use ARB context creation you must create a render context
>    //must be made active and destroyed 
>    HGLRC tempContext = wglCreateContext(hDC);
>    wglMakeCurrent(hDC, tempContext);
>
>    hRC = wglCreateContextAttribsARB(hDC,0, attribs);
>    wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL);
>    wglDeleteContext(tempContext);
>    wglMakeCurrent(hDC, hRC);
>
>    wglMakeCurrent(hDC,hRC);  //make rendering context current old style
> ```

Your comment

> in order to use ARB context creation you must create a render context must be made active and destroyed

is especially misleading. It is not about creating and destroing some legacy context for its own sake. It is about creating a context *to get the WGL extension function pointers*, which you simply do not do.

Since you are using GLEW's wglew functionality, it will declare all the necessary function pointers in `wglew.h`, but these function pointers are all initialized to `NULL`, so your call of `wglCreateContextAttribsARB` will just dereference the `NULL` pointer and crash.

Creating and making current a legacy OpewGL context will not magically initialize these pointers. You have to explicitely call `wglewInit()` to query these function pointers - and that is the only time you need `tempContext` being active.

Comment: can you be a bit more specific, because i followed your instruction and ran wglewinit() but the problems remains

Comment: okay i got it working i changed these things around: hDC = GetDC(hWnd); setupPixelFormat(hDC); HGLRC tempContext = wglCreateContext(hDC); wglMakeCurrent(hDC, tempContext);
initGL(hDC);hRC = wglCreateContextAttribsARB(hDC,0, attribs);
wglMakeCurrent(hDC, NULL); wglDeleteContext(tempContext);
wglMakeCurrent(hDC, hRC);

and now it works , but i am not getting the core profile context , because even without shaders its still drawing and also the getIntegerv() functions are returning opengl version 4.4 while i am requesting 3.2

Comment: You are not requesting a core profile. You request GL 3.1, which does not even have profiles. As per the spec, the profile flag is _ignored_ for such a request, and you get some version >= 3.1 which is _compatible_ to the requested version, which for your implementation seems to be a 4.4 compat profile.

Comment: there is still the problem of drawing without shaders, i havent used any shaders neither fragment nor vertex shader and i am still getting rendering to the window screen, shouldnt a core profile not have a default frag and vertex shader?

Comment: okay i found that when i use the intel (software renderer) that it still draws even with core profile selected , but when i switch to using only the graphics processor it doesnt draw the test triangle , so it must be something to do with the software renderer vs the graphics renderer , when i use the standard software renderer these is what initGL() returns : OpenGL version string is 4.4.0 - Build 20.19.15.4483
Glew version is 2.0.0
GL Major version 4
GL Minor Version 4
GLSL version is 4.40 - Build 20.19.15.4483
Vendor of OpenGL is Intel
Renderer version is Intel(R) HD Graphics 530

Comment: and here is the ouput from initGL when i use graphics hardware processor and it doesnt draw the triangle, so clearly it is to do with software renderer providing its own default shaders:OpenGL version string is 4.5.0 NVIDIA 369.09
Glew version is 2.0.0
GL Major version 4
GL Minor Version 5
GLSL version is 4.50 NVIDIA
Vendor of OpenGL is NVIDIA Corporation
Renderer version is GeForce GTX 970M/PCIe/SSE2
Window was created....
Window destroyed goodbye...bye

Answer (score 2):

> ```
>  //in order to use ARB context creation you must create a render context
>  //must be made active and destroyed
> ```

That's not why you [create a temporary rendering context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Creating_an_OpenGL_Context_(WGL)#Create_a_False_Context).

In Win32, you can access the basic WGL functions directly. But WGL extension functions require that you already have a rendering context, since that implementation is what actually provides those extensions.

So you create a temporary context, then *load WGL extensions*, then destroy the temporary context.

You skipped the middle part.

Also, you cannot set the pixel format of a Win32 HWND more than *once*. Since you probably want to use WGL extensions to pick the pixel format, that's a problem. As such, your temporary rendering context should be created for a temporary *window*, where you set the temporary pixel format.

Comment: do i load the WGL extension with "wglGetProcAddress("wglGetExtensionsStringARB")" is that what you mean by loading the WGL extensions?

Comment: @sporingGT: If you're going to use an extension loader like GLEW, then you should use its tools to load WGL extensions.

Comment: okay i got it working i changed these things around: hDC = GetDC(hWnd); setupPixelFormat(hDC); HGLRC tempContext = wglCreateContext(hDC); wglMakeCurrent(hDC, tempContext); initGL(hDC);hRC = wglCreateContextAttribsARB(hDC,0, attribs); wglMakeCurrent(hDC, NULL); wglDeleteContext(tempContext); wglMakeCurrent(hDC, hRC); and now it works , but i am not getting the core profile context , because even without shaders its still drawing and also the getIntegerv() functions are returning opengl version 4.4 while i am requesting 3.2